# Having difficulty in following a proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove that $A\cup \emptyset = A$ one has to prove that $x \in A\cup\emptyset \implies x \in A$. Let $x$ be a arbitrary element of $A \cup \emptyset$ then $x\in A $ or $x\in \emptyset$. The first case is trivial. For the second case you have to assume that $x\in \emptyset$ but this is against the definition of empty set. So how could you prove the second case.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x\in \varnothing$. This is absurd, by definition of the emptyset, hence anything follows. In particular $x\in A$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to prove: one, that $A\subseteq A\cup\emptyset$, and two, that $A\cup \emptyset \subseteq A$.

The first assertion is a tautology, for any element $x\in A$ shall belong to $A\cup \emptyset$.

The second assertion is shown as follows: let $x\in A\cup \emptyset$, i.e. $x$ belong to $A$ or to $\emptyset$. Assume $x\in\emptyset$. Since $\emptyset$ is the set such that there exists no element $y$ such that $y\in \emptyset$, the assumption is a contradiction in terms. Then, $x\not\in\emptyset$. It follows then that $x\in A$, as we wanted to show.

Comment: what if empty set is disguised as A.Then the contradiction won't help

Comment: If $A$ is also empty, then $x\in A\cup\emptyset$ is false, so the whole implication becomes true (vacuously).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about that.

Comment: That's it. As @Vsotvep has said, the implication becomes true. Think that propositions of the form $P\to Q$, with $P$ a false proposition are always valid.

Comment: One thing more let's suppose A isn't empty then if $x \in A \cup \phi $ and $x\in \phi $ then $x \in A$ becomes also vacuously true.

Comment: Except, @Anonymous, that $x$ cannot be in $\emptyset$. Recall that I only assume this to reach a contradiction. Read my argument's structure as follows: we either have $P$ or $x\in \emptyset$. Since $x$ cannot be an element of $\emptyset$, then $P$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A \cup \emptyset \neq A$. Then $(A \cup \emptyset)^c=A^c\cap U=A^c \neq A^c$, where $U$ is an universal set, if such exists. So $A \cup \emptyset = A$.

Warning, this is a naive approach.